# Bash multiple if statements to run different variants of script on different days

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm trying to write a bash script to run a daily incremental backup using rsync but the back up goes into a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday folder.

So instead of having 6 scripts running in cron I would like 1 script using ifs to determine if it's a monday run this command. but if its Wednesday run this, and if it's not Mon-Fri exit.

I am new to bash so I can see if being a way to maybe do this but I'm not fully sure as to how to set it up.

Below is what I have so far. very rough at the moment. once the ifs are sorted I will start cleaning the rest of the code up.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(date +%u) -e 1 ]]
then
rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
else
if [[ $(date +%u) -e 2 ]]
then
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/tuesday
else
if [[ $(date +%u) -e 3 ]]
then
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/wednesday
elselse
if [[ $(date +%u) -e 4 ]]
then
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/thursday
elselse
if [[ $(date +%u) -e 5 ]]
then
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/friday
else
if [[ $(date +%u) -e 6 ]]
then
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/saturday
else
    exit

fi
```

Slightly puzzled this script works when test on compileonline.com

```
$bash -f main.sh 
sending incremental file list rsync: opendir "/home/beach" failed: Permission denied     (13) rsync: opendir "/home/com" failed: Permission denied (13) 
rsync: opendir "/home/railo" failed: Permission denied (13) 
rsync: opendir "/home/webmaster" failed: Permission denied (13) 
rsync: mkdir "/home/backup/files/backupdaily/Thursday" failed: No such file or directory (2) 
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(576) [receiver=3.0.6] 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender] 
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600)
```

but if i try to run it i get:

[root@san-prod-01 backup]# bash ./backup_daily_v3.sh 
: command not foundh: line 4: '/backup_daily_v3.sh
: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token in '/backup_daily_v3.sh
: line 5: case $WeekDay in –

any suggestions?

Comment: What's this `-e` in the condition?  Typo?  Use `-eq` instead.

Comment: yes sorry like you saidshould be eq for equals

Comment: perhaps use `case` instead of nested if-then-else for readability. See e.g. [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/)

Comment: case looks good but i am now unsure as to how to start writing this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having cron start this script. Additionally, in this case (pun?) you will be better off using case.

```
#!/bin/bash
case $(date +%u) in

    1) # Monday  
        rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
        ;;
    2) # Tuesday  
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/tuesday
        ;;
    3) # Wednesday
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/wednesday
        ;;  
    4) # Thursday
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/thursday
        ;;
    5) # Friday
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/friday
        ;;
    6) # Saterday
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/saturday
        ;;
    7) # Sunday
        exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

[Update] updated script to use lower case letters for weekdays.[/Update] Because some days run roughly the same command, you could shorten your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
LinkDest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
WeekDay=$(date +%A |tr [A-Z] [a-z])

case $WeekDay in

    monday) rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
        ;;
    tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)   rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=$LinkDest /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/$WeekDay
        ;;
    sunday)    exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: thank you for your help. yes i will be using cron to run this script. i wanted 1 script rather than 6 so thank you for ur help i will give it a try

Comment: im getting this error?

'/backup_daily_v1.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'/backup_daily_v1.sh: line 1: `case $(date +%u) in

also i have noticed ifi have #!/bin/bash in my scripts they fail but if i remove this they run?   im running Centos Linux 6.5

Comment: $bash -f main.sh
sending incremental file list
rsync: opendir "/home/beach" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/com" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/railo" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/webmaster" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkdir "/home/backup/files/backupdaily/Thursday" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(576) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600)

Comment: [root@san-prod-01 backup]# bash ./backup_daily_v3.sh
: command not foundh: line 4:
'/backup_daily_v3.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'/backup_daily_v3.sh: line 5: `case $WeekDay in

Comment: @user3544713 #1. Regarding bash's location: type `which bash` to learn the path to bash. #2. The shell program would need to be run as root for permissions to read files in other users directories. #3. `y=$(date +%A)` will capitalize the first letter in the weekday. If you prefer a lower case, then use `y=$(date +%A |tr [A-Z] [a-z])` #4 Regarding case syntax error: I suspect that your not using bash for your shell.

Comment: #1 = /bin/bash
#2 script is ran from root access and crontab has adds root permision also
#3 i like the update for lower case
#4 i will check

Comment: update.....   the script is working.  my sh file got modified into dos not unix so once we ran dos2unix on the sh it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
backup_dir=/home/backup/files/backupdaily
weekday=$(LC_ALL=C date +%A | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')

case ${weekday} in
    monday)
        rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home "${backup_dir}"/monday
        ;;
    tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday)
        rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest="${backup_dir}"/monday /home "${backup_dir}/${weekday}"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```