# Rsync Multiple Sleeping Processes?

Tags: bash, process, cron, rsync, kill

[My rsync script for creating daily incremental backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129932/bash-multiple-if-statements-to-run-different-variants-of-script-on-different-daysync) is working pretty well now. But I have noticed after a week or so that I am left with hundreds of Sleeping Rsync Processes running. Has this to do with my script? Is there a command I can add to the script to stop this?

Comment: Please post the code you are running here, rather than linking to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
LinkDest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
WeekDay=$(date +%A)

case $WeekDay in

    Monday) 
            rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines     /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday
        ;;
    Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)   
            rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-    dest=$LinkDest /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/$WeekDay
        ;;
    Sunday)    
            exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

here is my entry in the crontab -e  logged in as root

```
#Backup Schedule
# Daily
* 0 * * * /usr/local/src/backup/backup_daily_v3.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Process View

```
  PID   USER    PRI NI  VIRT    RES     SHR     S   CPU%    MEM%    TIME+       COMMAND
1096    root    20  0   116M    1720    716     S   0.0     0.0     14:26.33    |- SCREEN
5169    root    20  0   105M    1428    1084    S   0.0     0.0     0:00.07     |  |- /bin/bash
4012    root    20  0   105M    1188    968     S   0.0     0.0     0:00.00     |  |- /bin/bash
1097    root    20  0   105M    980     676     S   0.0     0.0     0:00.34     |  |- /bin/bash
```